# Uploading File via Form

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to give the option to my users to upload a csv file and populate a database table with it.

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('funding/create') ?>

<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" /> Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Funding Record" />
```

My function in the funding controller:

```
public function create()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $uploaded = false;

    $target_path  =  "";
    $target_path  =  $target_path  .  basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        $uploaded = true;
    } 



    if (!$uploaded)
    {

        $this->load->view('funding/create');

    }
    else
    {
        //$this->funding_model->insert_funding();
        $this->load->view('funding/success');
    }
}
```

(For now, I only got to the stage where I want to check the file has been uploaded. However, CI returns:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: uploadedfile

Filename: controllers/funding.php

Line Number: 30
```

I tested the code in a mock, non-ci form I made and it worked... Any thoughts? :/ I thought $_FILE was a global php parameter.

Comment: Where's the opening `<form>` tag?

Comment: Apologies, there wasn't meant to be a </form> in the first place

Answer (score 0):

I am not very common with CI, but you should use `form_open_multipart` instead of `form_open` to add the multipart attribute which is necessary for uploading files.

Comment: Is there a special reason why you are not using the provided uploading class? https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html You can easily access the file information w/ `$this->upload->data()`

Answer (score 0):

Don't access `$_FILES`. I think CI disables them for security reasons. You need to use their upload class (which can give you security as well, like XSS filtering). The documentation is here: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Basically use this (from their docs, added some comments myself):

```
//Choose the upload path of your server here, 
//make sure it is chmodded to 777 otherwise it will never work
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/'; 
$config['allowed_types'] = 'csv'; //Only allow csv
$config['max_size'] = '100000'; //Also check this server side!!!

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

//Add the file input form name here
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('uploadedfile')) 
{
    $this->load->view('funding/create'); 
}
else
{
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    //$data contains filename etc. Update DB here.
    $this->load->view('funding/success');
}
```

Please be aware that your code was very unsafe (no checking for extensions for example). A malicious user could just upload a PHP file to your server and then execute it, potentially destroying your server/website/database/etc. You **must** do security checks!